# Magento admin not able to create new customer while creating new order

Tags: magento-1.8, magento-1.9, admin, orders, customer

While creating new order from backend i am getting number of jquery errors and i am not able to click "Add New Customer" button as well

[image]

Any suggestions to solve above issue ? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are missing a js file or there is some conflict.
First check if the file `js/mage/adminhtml/sales.js` is loaded in the page.
If it is, check if you have jquery or some other library loaded that might conflict with prototype.

Comment: yes sales.js is included & js is merged.

Comment: aha...maybe something is wrong with the merging. Try to disable the js merging. If it works, enable it again.

Comment: i have disabled merging but still its coming as merged and there is an extension which has external sales.js i have disabled that as well but no luck

Comment: If you altered a configuration and it doesn't seem to work, you flush cache.

Comment: yes i already flush cache many times.

Comment: Next step: did you apply the setting at the correct store view? Final step: are you using the standard Magento functionality or it's it replaced by an extension, that does not listen to the Magento configuration, but its own setting?

Comment: @Marius you were right, there was confliction with jquery used in header :)

Comment: @Melvyn thanks for your suggestions, i have resolved the issue.

Comment: @TBIInfotech Please write your solution as an answer and accept it.

Comment: @Marius In my case sales.js is not load, i have check in page source